# Recreating Connected Apps through C#

Tags: metadata-api, connected-apps, .net

We have connected apps that I wish to delete and recreate for our deployment process using OAuth2 Register through .Net.
I am able delete the app and then recreate it. But if I run the process again straight after, the newly created connected app is not found and I can't delete it and recreate it. If I go to Salesforce I can see the connected app is there. I found to resolve this I can go directly into Salesforce and click edit and save on the connected app. Now when I run my code the connected app is found ready for deletion and recreation and it works again. Is there a value I should possibly be passing to Salesforce to make sure the app is "active" as it seems it just requires a manual save on Salesforce and my code works.

Comment: Questions about implementation problems need to include a specific description of the problem (including exact errors and stack traces, if any) and _the code or metadata to reproduce the problem_. Please limit code inclusions to only the relevant elements, such as an MVR (minimum viable reproduction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not be deleting and recreating Connected Apps as a general rule. You only need once instance of it, and it need only live in your production/business org. As long as you have the client Id and client secret, you can use that app for any org you wish to connect to.